# How can I set the background of Word to a different default color?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

Default blue background and white text in Microsoft Word.

I have just moved to Word 2010 (Student Version now released) and although it is possible to create individual documents with a blue background it is not possible to set the program with a blue background as a default.

I understand this was discontinued with Office 2007.
The only way I can open a document with a blue background is to create a Template with a blue background and use that for each document I wish to create.

I'm sure there must be a method of hacking the registry to accomplish this. 
Can you assist?

Comment: the traditional method for enforcing such a default via templates was to make the change in the default template.  used to be the file **"normal.dot"**, but it's been about a decade since i dealt with MS Word heavily, so that could've changed since then.

Comment: Pretty much the same, except now it's "normal.dotx" and in Word 2007/2010 format.

Answer (score 1):

Have been able to accomplish a blue background.  Not through the registry, but by creating a Template using Normal.dot.  Very easy.

Answer (score 0):

On 2020-12-27 I tested updating `%appdata%\Microsoft\Templates\Normal.dotm` ([Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-normal-template-normal-dotm-06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea)) on Windows 10 with office 365. However, the background remains white for new documents.

**Alternative**
An alternative is to create a word template and opening the template will create a new word file.

To create the template:

1. Open new word document
2. Change background color (see design tab)
3. Save template as `*.dotx` or `*.dotm`.

For easy access you can:

- Save template on preferred location (e.g. desktop)
- Pin template to word in task bar (right click on word in task bar)
- Open template in word (open word > more templates > personal > your template)